# Android Studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code 255

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-studio-3.0, opengl-es-3.0

Trying to run a simple game in mid-development, made with OpenGLES 3. Upon starting a Pixel 2 XL emulator with 4gb of ram, I'm getting this message which seemed to come out of nowhere: "Emulator: Process finished with exit code 255". I've been using the emulator for sometime now without any major hiccups, but this one won't seem to boot. I've barely seen any mentions of this specific error online.

Answer (score 1):

- Your size on disk is not full - this's often happen due to creation of some virtual devices that are unused.
- The RAM size of emulator is not minimum as your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the Android Virtual Device Manager, and wipe data of the emulator you are trying to use.